# C# PostMessage within a timer

Tags: c#, postmessage

I've got a question about PostMessage. I'm trying to get this to work with one another

```
    private void roll_spin_timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Process P in processList)
        {
            if (P.ProcessName.Equals(processName))
            {
                IntPtr edit = P.MainWindowHandle;
                PostMessage(edit, WM_KEYDOWN, (IntPtr)Keys.R, (IntPtr)0);
            }
        }
    }

    private void kill_me_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Process P in processList)
        {
            if (P.ProcessName.Equals(processName))
            {
                IntPtr edit = P.MainWindowHandle;
                PostMessage(edit, WM_KEYDOWN, (IntPtr)Keys.Enter, IntPtr.Zero);
            }
        }

    }  


    #region Checkboxes
    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkBox1.Checked)
        {
            checkBox2.Enabled = false;
            textBox2.Enabled = false;
            roll_spin_timer.Interval = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
            roll_spin_timer.Start();
        }
        if (!checkBox1.Checked)
        {
            checkBox2.Enabled = true;
            textBox2.Enabled = true;
            roll_spin_timer.Stop();
        }

    }

          #region Checkboxes
    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkBox1.Checked)
        {
            checkBox2.Enabled = false;
            textBox2.Enabled = false;
            roll_spin_timer.Interval = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
            roll_spin_timer.Start();
        }
        if (!checkBox1.Checked)
        {
            checkBox2.Enabled = true;
            textBox2.Enabled = true;

            roll_spin_timer.Stop();
        }

    }

    private void checkBox2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkBox2.Checked)
        {
            roll_spin_timer.Interval = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
            roll_spin_timer.Start();
            checkBox1.Enabled = false;
            textBox2.Enabled = false;
            kill_me.Start();
        }
        if (!checkBox2.Checked)
        {
            roll_spin_timer.Stop();
            checkBox1.Enabled = true;
            textBox2.Enabled = true;
            kill_me.Stop();
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

It should press Enter every 15 seconds, when 'kill_me' timer is ticking. And it should press R every 30 seconds, when 'roll_spin_timer' is ticking.
Separately it works but when im trying to enable both at the same time things get messed up. It works every now and then, and that's it. I'm guessing there is an easy way to make it work, but I just don't know it YET!

How can I solve this problem? To be honest I wish I could fix it my self. I just need some sort of example. I hope you guys can help me out. The coding is probably terrible for people that use C# for a longer period time, I could use some tips & tricks!

Thanks in advance!

Yours Sincerely,

**MB**

Comment: I've added the code that activates them ;) I hope you can help me out

Comment: Is this definitely the right code? - you seem to have two copies of the same method, and the interval on kill_me_timer is never set.  What are checkbox1 and checkbox2 meant to control?

Comment: Checkbox1 should control Spin_roll_timer and checkbox2 should enabled both

Comment: And textBox2 contains the interval for the roll_spin_timer in milliseconds (i.e. 30000)?  Where is the interval for kill_me set?

Comment: In properties? I could change this very easy. But this shouldnt be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using System.Windows.Forms.Timer. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) you could read following:

> This Windows timer is designed for a single-threaded environment where
>   UI threads are used to perform processing.

Try to use another timer class, System.Timers.Timer or System.Threading.Timer.
Also you could try to write it using thread

Comment: I'd really want to know how to correctly use Thread, What about a background worker?

Answer (score 0):

What is really messed up here? Can you explain? Or you can try using single timer with 15 seconds interval and implement some kinda logic to handle 15 and 30 seconds interval operations. Do you need to iterate through processList every time or can you keep a reference to the interested Process and use it whenever timer hits?